# how to texture paint on top of a node texture?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, texture-painting, shader-nodes

I would like to texture paint on top of a texture made from nodes. Is there a way to do this without baking too?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to integrate hand painted textures with procedural textures without baking.  What is it that you have, and what is it that you want to do?

Comment: I don't have anything related to this right now but I run into this problem a few times, For example if you have a brick wall made with nodes and you want to paint some dirt on the corners with texture paint or draw graffiti on the wall.

Comment: Then yes, you can create a new texture, and, for example, mix/multiply your bricks with its color; or you can use your new texture as the fac to mix between two other procedural textures.  (Or procedural to mix between two hand-painted, or between one hand-painted and one proc, and so on....)

Comment: Could you show me the steps with pictures so I can understand the process better.

Comment: The problem is, there are about a million different things you could do, so that's why I suggested you show us what specific problem you're having trouble with.  If you don't have an actual problem right at this moment, maybe you could wait until you do, and then edit the question?

Comment: you can unwrap your object, create an Image Texture node in the Shader Editor, create a new image with transparent background, mix it with the existing texture with a MixRGB, and use the Alpha output of the Image Texture as factor in this MixRGB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nathan and moonboots mentioned: (and i can understand that for beginners a 2 sentences comment sometimes doesn't help - that happened to me often when i started learning Blender)

e.g.: you can use this node setup:

[image]

image:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]